# View XML Site Map IIS Express

Tags: asp.net, xml, iis

I am trying to create a site Map using the `web.sitemap` when trying to view the site map I have had the  `404.7 server error` which I have sorted with allowing the file extension in the `web.config` but now I have the problem of allowing the file type to be viewed. The error tells me to do the following:

```
To set a MIME type, run the following command in the IIS Express install directory: appcmd set     config /section:staticContent /+[fileExtension='string',mimeType='string']
The variable fileExtension string is the file name extension and the variable mimeType string is the file type description.
For example, to add a MIME map for a file which has the extension ".xyz": appcmd set config /section:staticContent /+[fileExtension='.xyz',mimeType='text/plain']
```

When I look in the folder I only see xml configurations files. 
Is there a way to add the MIME type in the `web.config` ? or do I have to do the IIS thing?

I have only allowed the file type:

```
<fileExtensions allowUnlisted="true">
      <remove fileExtension=".sitemap"/>
      <add fileExtension=".sitemap" allowed="true"/>
</fileExtensions>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the mimetype as well

```
<staticContent>
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".sitemap" mimeType="application/xml" />
</staticContent>
```